# Change the stroke/fill color of SF Symbol icon in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, sf-symbols

I am looking for a way to change the stroke / fill color of an SF Symbol icon in SwiftUI.

I have tried `.background(Color.red)` but that just changes the background of the whole icon (no change is applied to the actual icon itself) as implied. I also tried `.foregroundColor(Color.red)`which does nothing to the icon.

contents of content view are as follows:

```
var body: some View {
    Image(systemName: "person.circle").foregroundColor(.red)    
}
```

Comment: `Image(systemName: "person.circle").foregroundColor(.red)` draws a red person in a circle for me. What does it draw for you?

Comment: for me it remains a black icon. It could just be a xcode bug... At least that's what I'm hoping.

Comment: Please post a small, self-contained test. Create a new SwiftUI project and modify the default `ContentView` to demonstrate the problem. Then copy the definition of `ContentView` into your question.

Comment: Edited! Still black with a self contained project however.

Comment: Are you running the code, or using the preview? For me, the preview is showing the icon as black, but running it will change the color correctly

Comment: Oh! That seems to have solved my problem. Odd it doesn't show in the preview.

Comment: `Image(systemName: "person.circle").foregroundColor(.red)` will work, but I want to color  the custom logo like `Image("clock").foregroundColor(.blue)` and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 52):

You can change the stroke and fill color of a sf symbol icon using `foregroundColor(_ color: Color?)`

The following code:

```
Image(systemName: "flame.fill").foregroundColor(.red)
```

```
Image(systemName: "flame").foregroundColor(.red)
```

Should produce this:

[image: Filled and Stroked Flame SF Symbol Icons]

Here is the complete SwiftUI View Code

```
struct Icon : View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack{
            Image(systemName: "flame.fill")
            .foregroundColor(.red)
            Image(systemName: "flame")
            .foregroundColor(.red)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect. `foregroundColor` did the trick for me.  You would say `accentColor` would describe this functionality better but that one doesn't work.

Comment: Also note that `foregroundColor` has no effect on Image if you use a `Image(uiImage: UiImage("flame.fill"))`

Comment: The SFSymbol `.fill` or `.outline` variants are now automatically selected depending on the containing view. e.g. in `TabView` on Mac. Mac and iOS tab views don't both use `.fill`.

Comment: @Thomas you can get past the `foregroundColor` not working with a UIImage source by setting the rendering mode, e.g. `Image(uiImage: UiImage("flame.fill")).renderingMode(.template).foregroundColor(Color(.red))`. I still have some programatically created icons generated with PaintCode returned as UIImages.

Answer (score 29):

## iOS 15

from iOS 15 and with the SFSymbols 3, you can apply different layers of colors to a single symbol with the foreground style modifier:

```
Image(systemName: "person.circle")
    .resizable()
    .foregroundStyle(.red, .blue)
    .frame(width: 200, height: 200, alignment: .center)
```

[image: Demo 1]

---

## iOS 13 and 14

You can use a `ZStack` with different parts of the icon and apply different modifiers to each layer like:

```
///  I've used `GeometryReader ` for setting the size of elements dependent on each other

GeometryReader { proxy in 
    ZStack {
        Image(systemName: "circle")
            .resizable()
            .foregroundColor(.blue)

        Image(systemName: "person.fill")
            .resizable()
            .foregroundColor(.red)
            .frame(
                   width: proxy.size.width * 0.55,
                   height: proxy.size.width * 0.55,
                   alignment: .center
            )
    }
}.frame(width: 200, height: 200, alignment: .center)
```

[image: Demo 2]

<sub>**Note** that the old and new methods look slightly different but feel the same. (take a closer look at the roundness of the head)</sub>

Comment: using `.resizable` with `systemImage` is not recommended as it's transformed into something other than a font

Answer (score 25):

### iOS 15+

In iOS 15 we can use `foregroundStyle` to customise SF Symbols even more:

```
Image(systemName: "cloud.sun.bolt")
    .foregroundStyle(.gray, .blue)
```

---

See more at [this WWDC session](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10349/):

[image]

Answer (score 4):

One trick I figured out that works nicely for iOS 14 is to use the fill and non fill versions together to get two colors regardless of whether 14 or 15:

```
ZStack {
    Image(systemName: "person.circle")
        .foregroundColor(.white)
    Image(systemName: "person.circle.fill")
        .foregroundColor(.yellow)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is:

```
var body: some View {
    Image(systemName: "person.circle").accentColor(.red)    
}
```

Comment: This worked in an earlier beta. I think that currently, the correct way to do it is to use .foregroundColor(.red).

Answer (score 1):

SwiftUI now allows you to color parts (layers) of many of the SF Symbols. Some symbols have many layers.

This will color the symbol foreground blue:

```
Image(systemName: "person.circle").foregroundStyle(.blue)
```

If you want to color the circle differently from the person this will color the person blue and the circle gray

```
Image(systemName: "person.circle").foregroundStyle(.blue, .gray)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will draw the background of the icon in red and the lines in blue:

```
Image(systemName: "person.circle")
    .foregroundColor(Color.red)
    .background(Color.blue)
    .frame(width: size, height: self, alignment: .center)
    .clipShape(Circle())
```

Without clipShape there will be blue corners in the rectangle behind the circle.

Answer (score -1):

Just change the tint color. That did it for me.

Comment: tint color was the away I updated the .borderedProminent buttonStyle color.