# How to change SF Symbol icon color in UIKit?

Tags: ios, colors, uikit, sf-symbols

In `SwiftUI`, you can change the icon's color using `foregroundColor` modifier:
[Change the stroke/fill color of SF Symbol icon in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56709463/change-the-stroke-fill-color-of-sf-symbol-icon-in-swiftui)

Is there a way to change the color in `UIKit`? I looked up the documentation and didn't find anything related to it.

```swift
let configuration = UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(pointSize: 16, weight: .regular, scale: .medium)
let iconImage = UIImage(systemName: "chevron.right", withConfiguration: configuration)
```

Comment: iOS 15 in 2021 has new multi-colored icons in SF Symbols 3: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69304679/sf-symbols-hierarchical-palette-and-multicolor-rendering-mode-colors

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Use:

```swift
let icon = UIImageView(image: iconImage.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate))
icon.tintColor = .red
```

Comment: If you use a UIButton, template the image as above, then set the button tint color.

Comment: it used it without the second line but .image on "icon" , then I as usual in SwiftUI do `.foregroundColor(.red)` :)

Answer (score 85):

Use below code for changing SFSymbols icons color

```
let imageIcon = UIImage(systemName: "heart.fill")?.withTintColor(.red, renderingMode: .alwaysOriginal)
imageView.image = imageIcon
```

Before

[image]

After

[image]

Answer (score 9):

A small addition. I'm glad if it's of any help to anyone. We can combine not only different colours, but also different sizes and weight. For example you can do this:

```
let colorsConfig = UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(paletteColors: [.white, .magenta])
let sizeConfig = UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(pointSize: 30, weight: .bold)
let image = UIImage(systemName: "plus.circle.fill", withConfiguration: colorsConfig.applying(sizeConfig))
button.setImage(image, for: .normal)
```

Comment: Thanks! This is the only answer that shows how to use many colors if the icon supports many of them.

Comment: Incredible!  How the heck to you set the "fill" color (for symbols that have that) do you know ?!  It's easy on storyboard !

Comment: Just add third color in colours array. Somthing like: paletteColors: [.white, .magenta, .orange]. Orange will be your "fill" color.