# SF Symbols Hierarchical, Palette, and Multicolor rendering mode colors?

Tags: swift, uikit, uiimage, sf-symbols

At WWDC 2021 Apple announced SF Symbols 3, which will support new multi-color SF Symbols in iOS 15 and macOS 12.

> New color-rendering modes that add depth and emphasis to a symbol through layer annotation
> https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/sf-symbols/overview/

What is the syntax for creating such an image in UIKit and Swift?

```
let configuration = UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(pointSize: 18, weight: .regular, scale: .large)
// set colors...?

let image = UIImage(systemName: "1.circle", withConfiguration: configuration)
```

How does one use the the new `hierarchical`, `palette`, and `multicolor` rendering modes in UIKit?

These new rendering modes and colors are visible in the SF Symbols 3 app:

[image: SF Symbols Hierarchical Rendering Colors]

[image: SF Symbols Palette Rendering Colors]

Answer (score 59, accepted):

## SwiftUI

### Hierarchical

Use the `.foregroundStyle` modifier.

[From Apple:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/symbolrenderingmode/hierarchical)

> SwiftUI fills the first layer with the foreground style, and the others the secondary, and tertiary variants of the foreground style. You can specify these styles explicitly using the `foregroundStyle(_:_:)` and `foregroundStyle(_:_:_:)` modifiers. If you only specify a primary foreground style, SwiftUI automatically derives the others from that style.
>
> ```
> Image(systemName: "exclamationmark.triangle.fill")
>    .symbolRenderingMode(.hierarchical)
>    .foregroundStyle(Color.purple)
> ```

### Palette

Use the `.foregroundStyle` modifier with 2 or 3 colors as parameters.

[From Apple:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/symbolrenderingmode/palette)

> In this mode SwiftUI maps each successively defined layer in the image to the next of the primary, secondary, and tertiary variants of the foreground style. You can specify these styles explicitly using the `foregroundStyle(_:_:)` and `foregroundStyle(_:_:_:)` modifiers. If you only specify a primary foreground style, SwiftUI automatically derives the others from that style.
>
> ```
> Image(systemName: "exclamationmark.triangle.fill")
>    .symbolRenderingMode(.palette)
>    .foregroundStyle(Color.yellow, Color.cyan)
> ```

### Multicolor

Use the `.foregroundColor` modifier with 1 color, along with `.renderingMode(original)`.

[From Apple:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/image/renderingmode(_:))

> The multicolor behavior [is] achieved by using original template rendering mode, along with a blue foreground color. This mode causes the graphic to override the foreground color for distinctive parts of the image.
>
> ```
> Image(systemName: "person.crop.circle.badge.plus")
>     .renderingMode(.original)
>     .foregroundColor(.blue)
> ```

## UIKit

### Hierarchical

Use the `UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(hierarchicalColor:)` initializer.

[From Apple:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/symbolconfiguration/3810053-init)

> ```
> let config = UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(hierarchicalColor: [.systemTeal])
> imageView.image = image.applyingSymbolConfiguration(config)
> ```

### Palette

Use the `UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(paletteColors:)` initializer and two or three palette colors.

[From Apple:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/symbolconfiguration/3810054-init)

> ```
> let config = UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(paletteColors: [.systemTeal, .systemGray])
> imageView.image = image.applyingSymbolConfiguration(config)
> ```

### Multicolor

Use the `UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(hierarchicalColor:)` initializer and `preferringMulticolor()`.

[From Apple:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/symbolconfiguration/3810052-configurationpreferringmulticolo)

> Use this method (`preferringMulticolor()`) to acquire the multicolor variant of a symbol, if one exists. This method is the primary approach to retrieving multicolor symbols.
>
> For this color configuration to have an effect, your symbol image must have the following:
>
> - Its renderingMode set to `UIImage.RenderingMode.alwaysTemplate` or `UIImage.RenderingMode.automatic`.
> - Multicolor annotations. If your symbol doesn’t have multicolor annotations, the resulting image is a monochrome (template) symbol image. If you combine this configuration with a hierarchical or palette color configuration using `applying(_:)`, the resulting symbol uses the multicolor variant, if one exists, and defaults to the hierarchical or palette variant otherwise.
>
> ```
> let config = UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(hierarchicalColor: [.systemTeal]).preferringMulticolor()
> imageView.image = image.applyingSymbolConfiguration(config)
> ```

Comment: Good answer for SwiftUI... is there a way to use these in UIKit?

Comment: @pkamb I edited my answer to explain the UIKit options more thoroughly

Comment: this is it. Very nice.

Comment: How do you combine this with pointSize as in the original question?